# Component for a file storage

Tags: php, storage

Tell me, please, is there a php component to work with different file storage: Amazon S3, Rackspace cloudFiles, FTP and local? In order to have a single interface to work and not think about the internal implementation of file storage.

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides an [abstraction layer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) so you can implement your own I/O stream wrappers, although you'll quickly run into problems if you try to use flat files as a substrate for OLTP data.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those provides an SDK/API for PHP:

- [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)
- [Rackspace PHP Cloud Files API](https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles)
- [PHP FTP Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)
- [PHP Local Filesystem Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Comment: I guess he is looking for one interface to work with all of the above.

Comment: Interested in is a wrapper for different stores. In order to have a common interface.
If this component is not there, then I will do myself.

Comment: @Miron: Ah, I missed that part - sorry. Check symcbean's answer in that case.